# Node.JS Express Static Directory

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, post

I am using Node.JS express and mysql from NPM, i have successfully connected to the database and created a webpage to post a username and password, this function below queries the database and returns with a string like

```
[ RowDataPacket { username: 'foouser', password: 'foopassword', admin: 1 } ]
```

I am trying to use if to compare what the username coming from the html and the username coming from the MySQL server, unfortunately I have no way to isolate the username the mysql server gives me in its response.

I have tried the following.

rows.RowDataPacket.username <-- this returns undefined and crashes the script

rows.username <-- undefined

I have even tried to use the field variable, but it gives me nothing pertinent to the situation.

Is it possible that I could somehow access the username variable from the response above?

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
  con.query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='" + req.body.username + "' AND password='" + req.body.password + "'", function(err,rows,fields){
      if (!err){
          console.log(rows.username);
          res.sendFile('loginsucsess.html');
      } else {
        console.log("Could not get a response from server.");
        res.send('Internal Error');
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: Side note: Your query is currently rather susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (https://xkcd.com/327/). You should use [placeholders and parameters](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries) with your queries. Or, at least [escape the inputs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) when concatenating.

Comment: Thank you for that advice,  I escaped the inputs, I appreciate your information on how to secure this.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that by using this syntax

```
rows[0].username
```

I was able to access the variable